# Rails form displaying actual object text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view

I have a form that allows multiple records in my treatment_strategies table to be updated at once. It works fine, but for some reason it displays a massive amount of text above my input fields in the view itself. That text seems to be all the objects themselves:

```
[#<TreatmentStrategy id: 1, treatment_id: nil, agency_id: 1, name: "Develop agency leader     characteristics supporting i...", selected: false, created_at: "2014-10-08 04:48:13", updated_at: "2014-10-08 04:59:48", specifics: "", implementer: "", use_currently: false, feasible: false, previous_success: false, recommended: false>, #<TreatmentStrategy id: 2, treatment_id: nil, agency_id: 1, name: "Recruit, designate, and train leaders for the chan...", selected: false, created_at: "2014-10-08 04:48:13", updated_at: "2014-10-08 04:59:48", specifics: "", implementer: "", use_currently: false, feasible: false, previous_success: false, recommended: false>, #<TreatmentStrategy id: 3, treatment_id: nil, agency_id: 1, name: "Leaders mandate the use of the intervention strate...", selected: false, created_at: "2014-10-08 04:48:13", updated_at: "2014-10-08 04:59:48", specifics: "", implementer: "", use_currently: false, feasible: false, previous_success: false, recommended: false>, #<TreatmentStrategy id:
```

How can I get rid of all that text?

Here's my code:

```
                = form_tag update_individual_treatment_strategies_path, :method => "put", :id => "myForm" do |f|    
                = for treatment_strategies in @current_agency.treatment_strategies.order('created_at ASC')
                    =fields_for "treatment_strategies[]", treatment_strategies do |f|                   
                        %tr
                            %td
                                = treatment_strategies.name
                            %td
                                .custom-cell-left
                                    = f.check_box :use_currently
                                    Use Currently
                                    %br
                                    = f.check_box :previous_success 
                                    Previous success
                                .custom-cell-right
                                    = f.check_box :feasible
                                    Feasible
                                    %br
                                    = f.check_box :recommended
                                    Recommended
                            %td.text-center
                                = f.check_box :selected
                            %td
                                = f.text_area :specifics
                            %td
                                = f.text_field :implementer

                = submit_tag 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', style: "display:none;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: I had to switch the "=" to "-" for the line:

= for treatment_strategies in @current_agency.treatment_strategies.order('created_at ASC')

Still getting HAML dialed in...